# How to assign / access data from Mobx in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, mobx

I am currently using mobx and react native, I have created the files below where a user can get their geo location. The questions I have are:

1. In the function fetchLocation is this the correct way of assigning the returned position? (In terms of mobx best practice)
2. In fetchLocation how can I console log geo as I have tried and I get undefined.
3. In LocationScreen.js I am trying to access the value for geo how can I do this? I am able to run the fetchLocation function fine.
4. How can I do something similar to this -

   {this.props.store.geo ? Retrieved Geo Location : null}

Thanks in advance

LocationStore.js:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx'
class LocationStore{

  @observable geo = [];

  @action fetchLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {

        console.log(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        this.geo = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude
        }
        console.log(this.geo);
      },
      (error) => this.error= {error},
      { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000 },
    );
  }
}

export default new LocationStore()
```

LocationScreen.js

Comment: doesn't look like a mobx issue, have you tried to read the docs?  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#requestauthorization it says something about needing to do: `requestAuthorization()` maybe thats why you get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The clear concern here, is your use of @action without promise! I would suggest to ditch @action and @computed and just go for a stateless solution:

LocationStore.js:

```
import {observable} from 'mobx'
class LocationStore {

@observable geo = {};
@observable error = {};
@observable isLoading = false;

async fetchLocation() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    try {
       await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.geo = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude
                }
             this.isLoading = false;
            }
        );
    } catch (e) {
        this.error = e
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
}
export default new LocationStore()
```

component.js

```
async fetchLocation(){
    await this.props.LocationStore.fetchLocation();
}
render () {
    const { geo, error, isLoading } = this.props.LocationStore
    return (<View>
        <Button onPress={this.fetchLocation.bind(this)}></Button>
        {(!!isLoading)?<Text>{geo}</Text>:<Text>Loading</Text>}
    </View>)
}
```

Check-out 'async / await' for more information:
https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html